Trust self-sign CA in kubernetes
I have a self-sign root CA and copy and update the certificate in ubuntu nodes everything is okay. But if a pod wants to for example curl a HTTPS URL it shows a certificate error.
I did some research and I dont want to attach the CA as volume or init pod, I'm looking for a way to do it automatically.
Thanks in advance
The node can do curl https but the pod shows an error
